# Searching a BST for a double

Tags: c

I want to search through a binary search tree for a double (which is populated with doubles). When the function finds a value that is the new closest value it will print it on a CSV file. Once it finds the right value it will stop. This was working when I was searching for an integer, and the BST was populated with integers.

When I changed "int inputvalue" to "double inputvalue" I get a invalid operands error. I was wondering how I could change my code so that it could work with doubles.

```
void BSTSearch(node_t* root, double inputvalue, FILE* CSVfile)
{
    // Traverse the tree until root reaches a NULL
    while (root != NULL)
    {
        // The right subtree becomes the new tree
        if (inputvalue > root->data) {
            // Print to CSV
            fprintf(CSVfile, "%.6f,", root->data);
            root = root->right;
        }
        // The left subtree becomes the new tree
        else if (inputvalue < root->data){
            // Print to CSV
            fprintf(CSVfile, "%.6f,", root->data);
            root = root->left;
        }
        else {
        // If the inputvalue == root->data
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the structure of my BST.

```
typedef struct node node_t;

struct node {
    void* data;
    node_t* left;
    node_t* right;
};

/* bst type */
typedef struct {
    int num_elements;
    node_t* root;
    void (*del)(void*);
    int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*);
} bst_t;
```

Comment: The easiest would be just to get the types right. Change the type of the `data` member to `double*` and the compiler will tell you where you are doing things wrong. It is even not very convincing that this is even a pointer, a `double` member that holds the data directly would probably be much easier to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to compare a `double` to a `void*`. That of course won't work. Logically speaking, your example wouldn't be correct even for an integer value, since you would compare an int with a pointer.

You must cast and dereference your pointer since you'd like to compare the value from the address it points to, not the address itself:

```
if (inputvalue > *(double*)root->data) {
    // Print to CSV
    fprintf(CSVfile, "%.6f,", root->data);
    root = root->right;
}
// The left subtree becomes the new tree
else if (inputvalue < *(double*)root->data){
    // Print to CSV
    fprintf(CSVfile, "%.6f,", root->data);
    root = root->left;
}
```

Comment: to use this, you must also allocate memory for every data member you use

Answer (score 1):

I think you are evaluating your input data value against `root->data` which is a `void*`. You should evaluate after dereferencing: `*((double *)root->data)`.